# Multiple Subselects to same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a product-table and a table containing all parts of a product and the quantity.

Structure of products table:

```
id 
name
```

Structure of parts table:

```
id
productsId
partsId
quantity
```

Now I want to get all products and for every product the total quantity parts and quantity of different parts . The current solution is this query:

```
SELECT
    products.*,
    (
        SELECT count(quantity) 
        FROM product_has_part 
        WHERE product_has_part.productsId = products.id
    ) AS partsQty,
    (
        SELECT sum(quantity) 
        FROM product_has_part 
        WHERE product_has_part.productsId = products.id
    ) AS sumQty
FROM products
```

Now I have to subselects across the same table. So I think there must be a better way to create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p.f1, p.f2, p.f3 mean each field of p.

```
select p.f1, p.f2, p.f3  ... count(php.quantity), sum(php.quantity)
from products p
join product_has_part php
  on p.productsId  = php.productsId 
group by  p.f1, p.f2, p.f3 ..
```

Answer (score 1):

use join

```
Select *,count(quantity),sum(quantity)
From products p join 
product_has_part pp on pp.productsId = p.id
FROM products
```

or `Group by` use for count or sum for each id

```
Select *,count(quantity),sum(quantity)
From products p join 
product_has_part pp on pp.productsId = p.id
FROM products
Group by p.id
```

Comment: I forgot mysql isnt ansi, and  `group by p.id` will work